# How to track the total number of attempts made by the user to input data

Tags: java

I have made a very simple guessing game. But I want to count the sum of attempts a user made before finding the original number. That means once the Hidden number is matched with user input, it should tell how many numbers has been entered before the user won.

This is my code:

```
package guessinggame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hiddenNum = 10;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a numebr by guessing: ");

            int guessedNum = input.nextInt();


            if (guessedNum == hiddenNum) {
                System.out.println("Congratulation! Your number is matched");

                System.exit(0);

            } else if (guessedNum < hiddenNum) {
                System.out.println("Not matched! Try a bigger number");


            } else if (guessedNum > hiddenNum) {
                System.out.println("Not matched! Try a smaller number");

            }    
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: A simple counter variable is not very hard to implement

Comment: A comment stating that something is not very hard to implement is not a constructive comment. Provide some constructive comments or an answer or don't provide anything at all.

Comment: I take it this is homework? I can tell you already now that you are over-commenting the code. There are more comments than code for something as straight forward as this. `//checking another condition` is a terrible comment, it tells less than the code itself does.

Comment: August, Yea but what kind of counter it should be I am confused. I have if-else condition inside while loop, so I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: `Not sure != Can't do`, try first, you already have `int hiddenNum = 10;`. So you know the basics of how to initialize and declare variables. Go from there and increment the variable per guess.

Comment: Emz, Let's modify my code.

Comment: I really don't know why some people has this classic thought that "every programming question is homework". They should know that there is something to do that are beyond home work. Not all issue is related to schoolwork. May be it can be someone else's homework, but my purpose is to only practice.

Comment: @Simon I don't have that 'classic thought', I am currently assistant in a C course that has this exact exercise. If it is homework or not changes the answer to some extent.See my answer for a bit more in-depth.

Comment: Emz, it's because we r living in the same country, probably in the same institution (who knows?). The programming course has pretty much alike exercise in bachelor level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ition
                } else if (guessedNum < hiddenNum) {
                    System.out.println("Not matched! Try a bigger number");

```
                //checking another condition
            } else if (guessedNum > hiddenNum) {
                System.out.println("Not matched! Try a smaller number");

            }    
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: This moment is my Ah moment. Cant wait to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //storing the hidden number in a variable
    int hiddenNum = 10;
    //introducing the scanner class (for user input)
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //asking user to enter a random number

    int attempts = 0; // use as a counter

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a numebr by guessing: ");
        //Storing that into a variable
        int guessedNum = input.nextInt();

        attempts += 1;

        //Checking wheather the number is matched
        if (guessedNum == hiddenNum) {
            System.out.println("Congratulation! Your number is matched");
            //System.out.println("You have made total of " + attempts +" attempts to find the number!");
            //If matched number found, terminate the program
            System.exit(0);
            //checking another condition
        } else if (guessedNum < hiddenNum) {
            System.out.println("Not matched! Try a bigger number");

            //checking another condition
        } else if (guessedNum > hiddenNum) {
            System.out.println("Not matched! Try a smaller number");

        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: yea, thanks, the pretty much solution as the other one.

Comment: yea, you're welcome, the pretty much solution as the other one that I posted first. xox

Answer (score 0):

This reply is better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com but here it goes.

```
package guessinggame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hiddenNum = 10;
        int guessedNum = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean running = true;

        for (int i = 1; running; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number to guess: ");
            guessedNum = input.nextInt();

            if (guessedNum == hiddenNum) {
                System.out.println("Congratulation! Your number is matched");
                System.out.println("You have made " + i + " to find the number!");
                running = false;
            } else if (guessedNum < hiddenNum) {
                System.out.println("Not matched! Try a bigger number");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not matched! Try a smaller number");
            }    
        } 
    }    
}
```

Some changes to the code:

- You should avoid having `while (true)` and "randomly" terminating the program. Instead I introduced `boolean` variable. It can either hold the value of `true` or `false`. I put it as `true` in the start and later set it to `false` if the user guesses right.
- I removed the comments for now, generally you should use comments when the code doesn't explain itself. For example here it is a good reason to use it on the for loop. (A `while` loop is better practice here, I just wanted to show a `for` loop.)
- For the last condition check I removed the comparison, either it is equal, bigger or smaller. If we've tested equal and bigger all that remains is smaller, hence just the `else` there.